# GRPC reflection and grpc-web proxy does fail to find services

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-web

I can't figure out why web calls do not find the service GetNodeChannels.

I have registered the server with the associated services here:
https://github.com/lncapital/lnc/blob/frontend/cmd/lnc/lnc.go#L158-L168

And I'm creating the server struct and attaching the method here:
https://github.com/lncapital/lnc/blob/frontend/server/server.go

However neither reflection nor grpc-web seems to recognize them. Reflection simply does not show them and web calls respons with `Error: unknown service lncrpc.lncrpc`

Normal grpc calls work, but reflection and the web wrapped server does not.

Also: when I call: `fmt.Printf("%v", grpcServer.GetServiceInfo())` I get this in the terminal:

```
map[lightning.lncrpc:{[{GetNodeChannels false false}] lncrpc.proto}]
```

However I have never mentioned `lightning` anywhere. I do however import a proto file named `lightning.proto` in my proto file here: https://github.com/lncapital/lnc/blob/frontend/proto/lncrpc.proto#L3

Comment: Have you gotten this to work since posting?  What do you mean "reflection simply does not show them"?  What reflection APIs / etc are you invoking to see them?  Are you using grpcurl or grpc_cli?

Comment: I got the gprc-web to work. Have not had time to dig further in to reflection. It might be that I don't get "Evans" (grpc-cli reflection thing) to work. What tools do you use to test out reflection?

Comment: `grpcurl` works well.